# What would happen if they pushed 'YES' in Cube Zero?

Tags: analysis, cube-zero

In Cube Zero, the last movie of the trilogy, Owen made it to one of the exit points. Wynn and Dodd execute the exit procedure, so they asked two questions:

- Question one. Please state your name.

- (Because of memory loss) It's Owen I think.

- Question two. Do you believe in god?

- What kind of a god would do this to people? No!

And they pushed 'NO' and Owen burned in flames.

There are two questions here.

Question one: What would happen if they push YES?

Question two: Why has no one ever said YES to this question?

See [the scene on YouTube](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ZknfYBKAfT8)

Comment: As for my Assumption, If They Push The "Yes" Then It Is Unlikely They Will Be Set Free From The Cube Torture Room, However Since Owen Says "No" And He Was Burnt Alive. The Movie Doesn't Give Much More Informations About The "Yes" Button. There May Be Some Buried Questions About The "Yes" Button In Cube Zero. For Me, If They Say Yes, Then Maybe They Will Be Set Free. Who Knows? :-P

Answer (score 1):

Since no one ever said "Yes", we'll never know what would happen.  As I recall, the Cube was a Psychology experiment.

Again, there's no way to know if anyone ever said "Yes".  We do know that the people inside the cube are either death row inmates or political prisoners, and that no one gets out alive.  Kazan, the autistic savant from the first movie who walked out into a haze of light, is actually one of the techs (Eric) from Cube Zero.  But that was a different cube.  Kate, from Cube 2: Hypercube, escapes by jumping out into the blackness, but is executed after her "exit interview".  Again, that was a different cube.  There's no way to know whether or not the first cube, the one in Cube Zero, was meant to allow people to exit.  Based on the facts that it was filled with death row inmates and political prisoners, it's very possible it was meant to be a death trap.

Comment: No, they imply that the first cube and cube zero are the same cube.